# How to migrate OpenID Connect with OpenID 2.0 using JOpenID?

Tags: java, web-applications, openid, openid-connect, jopenid

I am currently using JOpenID 1.07 in one of my running web applications in order to authenticate and track users using their Google or Yahoo ID.

But, as OpenID 2.0 has been deprecated by Google and will be shut down after 20th April, I am really getting no clue what to do in order to be able to log in to the app after April 20th?

My question is, can JOpenID be used for OpenID authentication for OpenID Connect? Is there any change in code in my app that is needed for migrating my app with OpenID Connect using JOpenID? Or, is there any updated version of JOpenID for OpenID Connect?

My current application is running with OpenID authentication using JOpenID. Any idea or resources that could help me here?

Comment: Can you please not SHOUT at us in your title?

Comment: Guess you should've started working on this more than a week before such a large change.... I mean, Google must have given some notice that this was happening. Also, no one is just going to GIVE you the code because that is not what StackOverflow is for, and you are even less likely to get an answer if you say it is 'very urgent' because people are disinclined to dig you out of your self-created hole. Deliberately misspelling words is just irritating. You are not going to get an answer with the question in this state

Comment: All questions are equally important here so I removed "very urgent" part from your post. Also "Any idea or *resources* that could help me here???" asking for resources is off-topic on Stack Overflow (see point 4 of http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), consider [edit]ting your post and removing this part.

Answer (score 0):

You need to migrate to OpenID Connect. The JOpenID library does not support that. Choose a Java library that supports OpenID Connect from: http://openid.net/developers/libraries/ and change your code to use it.